# Git log graph, display how two branches are diverging

Tags: git

We would like to view a graph of how two branches are diverging. Running `git log --oneline --graph` displays only the current branch. How do we include both branches in the graph?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`git log` takes zero or more commits as arguments, showing the history leading up to that commit. When no argument is given, `HEAD` is assumed. For your case, you want to supply the two branch heads you want to compare:

```
git log --graph --oneline currentbranch otherbranch
```

If it doesn't display too much, you can simplify this by using

```
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

which acts as if you had specified every reference in `.git/refs` as the commits to display.

Comment: Both of these commands show the entire history. Is there a way to graph only the changes on each branch since the branch point?

Comment: @John I think you want `git log --graph --oneline current branch...otherbranch`, which shows all commits reachable from one of the two branch heads, but not from both.

Comment: With that command, the branch structure doesn't appear in the output. Instead the commits appear as a flat list, as if `--graph` wasn't used.

Comment: Nice alias: `cmp = log --graph --online HEAD` to use `git cmp OTHERSHA`

Answer (score 41):

I had the same issue and landed here, but no answer helped me to display *how two branches are diverging*. Eventually I did experiment myself and found this worked.

Given branch `A` and branch `B`, I want to see where they diverged.

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate A B `git merge-base A B`^!
```

Note: Don't forget there is `^!` at the end. (It excludes the parents of the commit returned by `merge-base`.)

**UPDATE**

The one line command above isn't working in case merge base is more than one. In this case do this:

```
git merge-base A B -a
# e.g. output XXXX YYYY
git log --oneline --graph --decorate A B --not XXXX^ YYYY^
```

Comment: This should be the preferred solution.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If anybody wants an alias, here you go. Tested on Bash 5.0.18 macOS Mojave   diverge = "!f() { if [[ $# -lt 1 ]] || [[ $# -gt 2 ]]; then >&2 echo \"Usage: git diverge BRANCH1 [BRANCH2]\"; return 1; fi; branch1=\"$1\"; branch2=\"${2:-HEAD}\"; base=\"$(git merge-base \"$branch1\" \"$branch2\")\" && git lg1-specific \"$branch1\" \"$branch2\" \"$base\"^!; }; f"

Answer (score -2):

```
git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all
```

Comment: Two requests. 1. Could you please provide a simplified version that answers the question without providing extra functionality. 2. Could you explain how to only show the two branches rather than all branches.